# Typescript: TypeError is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm fairly new to Typescript and React. I've been trying to implement the `react-rewards` npm library and I have solved all except one issue.

```
type Props = {}

class Surprisebutton extends Component<Props>{
    reward: any;

    render() {
        return (
            <Reward 
            ref={(ref) => { this.reward = ref }}
            type='memphis'>
                <Button onClick={this.reward.rewardMe()} style={styles.button} variant="contained" color="primary">
                    Surprise!
              <FavoriteIcon style={{ marginLeft: 10 }} />
                </Button>
            </Reward>
        )
    }
}
```

After running `npm start` I get an error which says `TypeError: this.reward is undefined`. What is the best way to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with TypeScript. TS is only a compiler and linter and you're getting a runtime error. It's this line:

```
this.reward.rewardMe()
```

The `ref` gets assigned after the component fully mounts and `rewardMe()` is attempting to call it immediately. This is also a secondary mistake. You don't want to use the `()` invocation or the function is going to immediately fire (and never stop).

The line should be

```
<Button onClick={this.reward.rewardMe} style={styles.button} variant="contained" color="primary">
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew! Checking this currently

Comment: I get the `Property 'reward' does not exist on type 'Surprisebutton'.` error when trying this approach as well. Declaring reward as a property by using `reward: any;` before `render` seems to get rid of the error in the compiler but when running `npm start` I still get the `TypeError: this.reward is undefined` error in browser.

Comment: You changed the `onClick` handler and it still did not work? There is a chance that the library doesn't accept a `ref` prop. `Property 'reward' does not exist on type 'Surprisebutton'` is a typescript type definition. `TypeError` is a javascript error. If you got it immediately without clicking the button, then you forgot to change the click handler

Comment: I actually did change the `onClick` handler. Also, this implementation is directly from their documentation [https://github.com/thedevelobear/react-rewards]

I'm also seeing a suggestion under `ref={(ref)...` which states `Parameter 'ref' implicitly has an 'any' type, but a better type may be inferred from usage.`

Comment: Excuse me but there is an example using it with functional componets?

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong because I never used this package but according to documentation/[Useage](https://github.com/thedevelobear/react-rewards#usage) topic. They are not initializing `reward` variable. Try removing that, Here's the fixed version

```
type Props = {}

class Surprisebutton extends Component<Props>{

render() {
    return (
        <Reward 
        ref={(ref) => { this.reward = ref }}
        type='memphis'>
            <Button onClick={this.reward.rewardMe()} style={styles.button} variant="contained" color="primary">
                Surprise!
          <FavoriteIcon style={{ marginLeft: 10 }} />
            </Button>
        </Reward>
    )
  }
}
```

Again I might be wrong but according to the github page i thinks that's the only thing i can infer.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, will check this and let you know if it works or not

Comment: This doesn't seem to work Shivam, I get the `Property 'reward' does not exist on type 'Surprisebutton'.` error.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `onClick` to something like this:

```
onClick={() => {this.reward.rewardMe()}}
```